# Addition of time type column

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, time

I don't know how to add time

**WrokController**

```
if($request->status === 'completed')
    {
        $t = 0;
        $alltime = Work::where('project_id', $project->id)->get();
        foreach($alltime as $time)
        {
            $t = $t + $time->work_time;
        }
        $project -> fill(['total_work_time' => $t])->save();
    }
```

But isn't there a good way to do this?

Comment: share code for `$project` also ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut I want to add the total to $ project.

Comment: what is your value for `$time->work_time`?? an integer??

Comment: If you have `$project`, you can just do `$project->total_work_time = $t; $project->save()`.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon time type "11:11"

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Thank you did not know how
But you can't add well before saving

Comment: @su3158 when you are using fill, you have the model instance, right, then why you can not just update property of the model!

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I thought but I couldn't come up with anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum it with interval,

```
$base_time = new DateTime();
$time_now = clone $base_time;
foreach ($alltime as $time) {
    $array = explode(':', $time);
    $base_time->add(new DateInterval(sprintf('PT%dH%dM', $array[0], $array[1])));
}
$sum_of_diff = $time_now->diff($base_time);
```

Comment: Call to undefined method app \ Work :: diff () came back

Comment: what your `Work`?

Comment: Work is class name

Comment: diff is the method of Datetime.

Comment: Why you call diff on Work?

Comment: I have no idea why it is called in Work

Comment: @su3158 check it http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c30b51bc9e7cec18eb2fb4dbb84ad5dc82da4d2a